# SceneKit: how to transform content of SCNMaterial?

Tags: textures, transform, scenekit

I create SCNNode with SCNBox,

```
SCNBox *wallBox = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:width height:100 length:4 chamferRadius:0];

SCNMaterial *allMaterial = [SCNMaterial new];
allMaterial.diffuse.contents = @"allwall.png";

SCNMaterial *smallMaterial1 = [SCNMaterial new];
smallMaterial1.diffuse.contents =@"bottomwall.png";
        
SCNNode *rightwall = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:wallBox];
        
rightwall.geometry.materials = @[smallMaterial1,allMaterial,smallMaterial1,allMaterial,allMaterial,allMaterial];
```

but the back of texture direction is wrong.

[image]

[image]

I  want two direction is same,how to transform content of  SCNMaterial ? how to use "contentsTransform"?

Comment: hi, David, I can't use stackoverflow very well. Is not deleted “enter image description here” pictures can be displayed？

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem using this answer: [SceneKit, flip direction of SCNMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284781/scenekit-flip-direction-of-scnmaterial?rq=1)

```
rightwall.geometry.materials = @[smallMaterial1,allMaterial,[smallMaterial1 copy],allMaterial,allMaterial,allMaterial];
    NSArray *allMaterial = rightwall.geometry.materials;
    SCNMaterial *smallMaterial2= allMaterial[2];
    smallMaterial2.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1,1,1);
    smallMaterial2.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
    smallMaterial2.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
```